# How do I check which minimum API is the feature available for?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner Android developer and it happens a lot of times that when I'm developing an app, I accidently put in a lot of features that are only supported by 3.0+ or even 4.0+. For example, implementih on/off switch makes app available only for 4.0+ (as far as i know, maybe i'm wrong)  and implementih admob ads makes it available for 3.0+ (what my tests have shown so far). I know I could do a research on every single feature on official docs, but is there a better website that offers such service? A website where you can select a certain API and it shows which features are available for it or something like that.

Comment: How would that be different from the official docs?

Comment: Just define android:mimSdk="" in manifest.xml then compiler will show you error if it is not available in minSdk API level.

Comment: @kettu that is not true. compiler errors are shown if the feature is not available for the `targetSDKVersion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com), you can filter by API level using the dropdown on the left hand side:

[image]

This will grey out or fade any classes and methods that did not yet exist as part of the API you've selected